# Format JSON into array $variable

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a large JSON that has the following contents:

```
  {"createTx": { 
    "inputs": [{
    "address": "mtFYoSowT3i649wnBDYjCjewenh8AuofQb",
    "value": 0.00009
}],
"outputs": [{
    "address": "mmskWH7hG9CJNzb16JaVFJyWdgAwcVEAkz",
    "value": 0.00018
}],
"fee":  {
    "address": "mmskWH7hG9CJNzb16JaVFJyWdgAwcVEAkz",
    "value": 0.00023141
}},  "wifs" : [
    "cUGddnJmuzfzpWXNwt1SRnQ8GMqZdQ1vg8BtwjG8f275pvExPzaX", "cSEjySAREyai8eQhgoqixzmxCeSP8QtbwHxptL8ijofg68ZMjoud", "cV2u6dqfiQthWfPixJ7ucFW5Tza1ubLr6ipM35vSTy9xGEKbCbaJ"]}
```

And in order to run it inside of a CURL POST I need to put it in a $variable in this type of format:

```
  $data = array("createTX" => "","inputs" => array ("1MfyBywPTSj9aAPr8cccCTcch71fd4vkDA" ) );
```

I need the entire JSON inside the $data variable.

Comment: What's wrong with `json_decode()`?

Comment: I have no idea how json_decode could help. I need The JSON inside of the $data to do a post curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

In order to use this JSON string in PHP directly, use PHP's [NOWDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) or [HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax like below:

```php
$json = <<< JSON
{"createTx": {
    "inputs": [{
    "address": "mtFYoSowT3i649wnBDYjCjewenh8AuofQb",
    "value": 0.00009
}],
"outputs": [{
    "address": "mmskWH7hG9CJNzb16JaVFJyWdgAwcVEAkz",
    "value": 0.00018
}],
"fee":  {
    "address": "mmskWH7hG9CJNzb16JaVFJyWdgAwcVEAkz",
    "value": 0.00023141
}},  "wifs" : [
    "cUGddnJmuzfzpWXNwt1SRnQ8GMqZdQ1vg8BtwjG8f275pvExPzaX", "cSEjySAREyai8eQhgoqixzmxCeSP8QtbwHxptL8ijofg68ZMjoud", "cV2u6dqfiQthWfPixJ7ucFW5Tza1ubLr6ipM35vSTy9xGEKbCbaJ"]}
JSON;

$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: No I am trying to post these. I need them in a variable.

Comment: Updated. This what you are looking for?

Comment: the output from your code does look close, just need to properly get in $data